# Text Query with additional Criteria and Sort

Tags: mongodb

This is the data structure in my MongoDB: (There can be results of different languages for every `videoId` field)

```
...
{
  id: '5123',
  description: 'lorem ipsum',
  langcode: 'eng',
  videoid: '1523'
}
{
  id: '6234',
  description: 'lorem ipsum',
  langcode: 'eng',
  videoid: '12345'
}
{
  id: '1525',
  description: 'lorem ipsum',
  langcode: 'rus',
  videoid: '12345'
}
...
```

To output the results I do a text search via `{ $text: { $search: query } }` and add the score field with `{ score: { $meta: 'textScore' } }`. The next steps are to sort by the `score` and to `skip` by a certain offset and `limit` the results by some number.

**Problem:**
The output can have results with the same videoId and that is the problem. I only want the first result for a distinct videoId in the list. So if there are five items with the same `videoId` then I want to keep the one with the highest `textScore` and discard the rest.

**One Solution:** ... filter the output manually ... 
The way I do this now is by filtering the result manually with JavaScript. I was hoping for a better way to do this all in MongoDB, because that would probably be faster.

Comment: What do you mean by "distinct"? In the above example are you simply expecting to get the result for a single value of `langcode`? Does this then contain multiple values of `videoid` or are there only really multiples by `langcode`? How do we deal with the text search? Is is supposed to match terms in different languages? Is it actually a "word or phrase" search, or is it really better suited to `$regex`?

Comment: The text search input is a string. The whole thing is the output of a input search field.

By `distinct` I mean the mongoDB function (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/), but that didnt work, since it only outputs the value that is used for the distinction.

To further explain: I search different track data for the search Text and sort it by the search score. Every track has a videoId and tracks of different languages can have the same videoId. However, I want only one (the first in the list) track for each distinct videoId.

Comment: I'm asking you to edit and elaborate on your very unclear question. I think I put a bit more effort into what I was asking against a single line response. It's been dead for a week. I guess noone else gets it either. Try to be more clear.

Comment: Please stop commenting and actually [Edit the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44550827/edit). The description of the problem belongs in there. Don't quote functions, just tell us what you really want to do.